# why is my MeanIou of validation not increasing for semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

I am training a sematic segmentation model for classification of crops/weeds, the problem is my model does well on training , it shows a good MeanIOU but not on validation , here is the model code :

```
def convolution_block(
    block_input,
    num_filters=256,
    kernel_size=3,
    dilation_rate=1,
    padding="same",
    use_bias=False,
):
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        num_filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
        padding="same",
        use_bias=use_bias,
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
    )(block_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(dspp_input):
    dims = dspp_input.shape
    x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dspp_input)
    x = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1, use_bias=True)
    out_pool = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)

    out_1 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=1, dilation_rate=1)
    out_6 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=6)
    out_12 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=12)
    out_18 = convolution_block(dspp_input, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=18)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_pool, out_1, out_6, out_12, out_18])
    output = convolution_block(x, kernel_size=1)
    return output
```

```
def DeeplabV3Plus(image_size, num_classes):
    model_input = keras.Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(
        weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input
    )
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(x)

    input_a = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // 4 // x.shape[1], image_size // 4 // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    input_b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    input_b = convolution_block(input_b, num_filters=48, kernel_size=1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_a, input_b])
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = convolution_block(x)
    x= layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        size=(image_size // x.shape[1], image_size // x.shape[2]),
        interpolation="bilinear",
    )(x)
    model_output = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)


def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    num_classes = y_pred.shape[-1]
    iou = []
    y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    for i in range(num_classes):
        true_class = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true[:,:,:,0], i), 'int32')
        pred_class = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_pred, i), 'int32')
        inter = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(tf.cast(true_class, 'bool'), tf.cast(pred_class, 'bool')), 'float32'))
        union = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_or(tf.cast(true_class, 'bool'), tf.cast(pred_class, 'bool')), 'float32'))
        iou.append((inter + 1e-7) / (union + 1e-7))
    return tf.reduce_mean(iou)


model = DeeplabV3Plus(image_size=IMAGE_SIZE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
model.summary()
```

I am using DeepLabV3+ to train it , I tried adding droput layers to reduce the overfitting , but the problem is if i plot the predication , i see that the model is predicting weed and crops both accurately[[image]] in the validation images  , but why does the MeanIou not represent that. In the given image, the left of the that is raw image , with weed highlighted in yellow , and as you can see the model predicts the weeds correctly (In purple) but still meanIoU is very low , can someone explain why that is.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEtkJ.jpg)

Comment: If you have good metric on train set and  not good on validation. It can means overfitting. Or that your model is bad. In any case this question about ML/AI not about programming. So this is off-topic. Delete it please.